# How to map tuples with persistent state in Trident?

Tags: stream, state, apache-storm, trident

I'm learning [Trident](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-API-Overview) framework. There are several methods on Trident [`Stream`s](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/storm/trident/Stream.html) for aggregation tuples within a batch, including [this one](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/storm/trident/Stream.html#aggregate%28backtype.storm.tuple.Fields,%20storm.trident.operation.Aggregator,%20backtype.storm.tuple.Fields%29) which allows to preform a stateful mapping of the tuples using [`Aggregator`](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/storm/trident/operation/Aggregator.html) interface. But unfortunately a built-in counterpart to additionally persist the map state, like other 9 overloadings of `persistentAggregate()`, only with `Aggregator` as an argument, is not present.

Thus how can I implement the desired functionality by combining lower-level Trident and Storm abstractions and tools? It is pretty hard to explore the API because there is almost no Javadoc documentation.

In other words, `persistentAggregate()` methods allow to end stream processing with updating some persistent state:

```
stream of tuples ---> persistent state
```

I want to update persistent state and emit different tuples by the way:

```
stream of tuples ------> stream of different tuples
                  with
            persistent state
```

`Stream.aggregate(Fields, Aggregator, Fields)` doesn't provide fault-tolerance:

```
stream of tuples ------> stream of different tuples
                  with
          simple in-memory state
```

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate. Your question is not clear

Comment: @GlobalWarrior see question update

Comment: Can you not release two separate stream with the same set of tuples? One of them persist state while others does the modification you want.

Comment: @GlobalWarrior mapping is stateful. To emit a new tuple, I need to know the current state.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new stream from a state using the method [TridentState#newValuesStream()](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/storm/trident/TridentState.html#newValuesStream%28%29).
This will allow you to retrieve a stream of the aggregated values.

For illustrative purpose, we can improve the [example in Trident documentation](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-tutorial#illustrative-example) by adding this method and a Debug Filter :

```
FixedBatchSpout spout = new FixedBatchSpout(new Fields("sentence"), 3,
    new Values("the cow jumped over the moon"),
    new Values("the man went to the store and bought some candy"),
    new Values("four score and seven years ago"),
    new Values("how many apples can you eat"));
spout.setCycle(true);

TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();        
topology.newStream("spout1", spout)
    .each(new Fields("sentence"), new Split(), new Fields("word"))
    .groupBy(new Fields("word"))
    .persistentAggregate(new MemoryMapState.Factory(), new Count(), new Fields("count"))                
    .newValuesStream().each(new Fields("count"), new Debug());
```

Running this topology will output (to the console) the aggregated counts.

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't need a stream of aggregated counts. I want to transform the values stream statefully. [This](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/storm/trident/Stream.html#aggregate%28backtype.storm.tuple.Fields,%20storm.trident.operation.Aggregator,%20backtype.storm.tuple.Fields%29) method solves the issue, except `Aggregator` class doesn't support persistency.

Comment: If I understand, you want to transform tuples according to previous state, then update state and emit transformed tuples. 

Can you confirm that?

Comment: According current state. Simply speaking, I would be satisfied with persisting implementation of `Aggregator`, but since it doesn't exist (in the standard Storm distribution, at least), I'm looking for different approaches.

Comment: Did you try with `stateQuery()`?